# How to change colors in d3.js and angular-charts.js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js, angular-chart

I am new to D3.js and angular-charis.js

my data like

```
$scope.data1 = { series: ['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec'], data: [{x:'Jan',y:[12150]},{x:'Feb',y:[0]},{x:'Mar',y:[10]},{x:'Apr',y:[64]},{x:'May',y:[2381]},{x:'Jun',y:[578]},{x:'Jul',y:[312]},{x:'Aug',y:[0]},{x:'Sep',y:[8700]},{x:'Oct',y:[17540]},{x:'Nov',y:[20190]},{x:'Dec',y:[1467]}] };

$scope.config = {
title: '',
tooltips: true,
labels: false,
mouseover: function() {},
mouseout: function() {},
click: function() {},
legend: {
  display: true,
  //could be 'left, right'
  position: 'right'
}
```

};

**HTML**

```
 <div id="chart1" ac-chart="'bar'" ac-data="data1" ac-config="config1" class="grpah-section"></div>
```

My result is displaying like wise:

[image]

But, I want Result displaying For each Individual X-axis bars displaying colors according to month indicating colors

Comment: could you please provide minimal working fiddle or something like that?

Comment: I am doing this task by reference of 
http://plnkr.co/edit/T9J7bz?p=preview

Comment: one workaround is give in series nulls, like this [{x:"jan", y:[10]},{x:"feb", y:[null, 400]}, .... {x:"Dec", y:[null, null, ..... nulls, 300]} ] but this is not great, I have looked on lib docs, actually it hasn't :) Ill suggest to switch to another one or create your own directive using D3.

Comment: My data is coming dynamically..Max my columns come nearly 900 to 1000